# How to return multiple values from node js to typescript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, api, authentication

I have the below node js post api to return a token, but I want it to return the token plus email, id, etc of the user:

```
app.post('/auth', function (req, response) {
    const body = req.body;

    console.log(req.body);

    let query = `select * from users where email = "${req.body.email}" and password = "${req.body.password}"`;

    databaseConnector.query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error, 'Error occurred with /auth/ API...');
        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
            console.log(result);

            var token = jwt.sign({ userID: result.id }, 'todo-app-super-shared-secret', { expiresIn: '2h' });

            console.warn(token);

            response.send({
                token: token,
                email: result.Email,
                firstName: result.FirstName,
                Id: result.Id
            })
        }
        else {
            return response.sendStatus(401);
        }
    })
});
```

This if the code from my client to retrieve the token details, it works but except it always return token only:

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
return this.http.post<LoginClaim>(`${environment.baseURL}/auth`, { email: username, password: password })
  .pipe(
    map(result => {
      console.error(result);
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', result.Token);

      this.setLoginDetails(result.Token);
      return true;
    })
  );
```

}

I expected it to return data in this format:
{token: tokeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeen,email: example@email.com, firstName: John, Id: 1234 }

But it only returns:
{token: xxxxxxxxxxxx }

As per my research it looks good, what could I be missing out?

Comment: Looks like the `result` is an object that doesn't have properties `.FirstName`, `.Email`, and `.Id`. Are you sure the casing is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The error was I should have used [0] as the result was an array:

```js
response.send({
  token: token,
  email: result[0].Email,
  firstName: result[0].FirstName,
  Id: result[0].Id
})
```